# Confused about the functioning of a QRE1113 reflectance sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, parallel, circuits, photoresistor

First year IT student here. I've been stuck on a problem involving a QRE1113 sensor, in which we were given the schematics below:

[image]

From my understanding so far, the reflectance sensor is divided into two parts, a LED which emits IV and a phototransistor which captures it after it is reflected from the target object.

We were asked to find the resistance value of R2 in order for a V-out signal of 1.4V to correspond to a value of 0.36ma for current I2.

The answer is 10Kohms, although I'm having a hard time understanding how to get there.

Since there are two currents, this can't be a voltage divider as I initially assumed, so does that mean the circuit is in parallel?

But if so, shouldn't the voltage across R2 equal the voltage across R1 and the input voltage of 5V instead of 1.4?

I know I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: No, because the resistors are not connected between same nodes so they won't have same voltage over them. Do you see what they have in common (if any)? Simply ask yourself, what is voltage on each end of R2 and what current flows through it.

Comment: The little arrow on transistors should always point downward.  Rearrange the schematic this way, and it should be more clear.  Try clicking the edit link below your question and experiment with the built-in schematic editor.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't help that the transistor is drawn in that orientation. \$I_1\$ is labelled ambiguously, so it's not clear if it's total current from the 5V source, or just current through R1. A little shuffle to clear everything up:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvMJs6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now it's clear that the paths for \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ are completely independent, while sharing the same +5V source. In other words [R1+D1] is in parallel with [R2+Q1], and apart from having the same potentials at their ends, they are otherwise unrelated.

Given Q1's collector potential \$V_{OUT}=+1.4V\$, Kirchhoff's voltage law will reveal the voltage across R2:

$$ V_{R2} = 5V - 1.4V = 3.6V $$

Now, with Ohm's law, the resistance R2 that will pass \$I_2=0.36mA\$ with 3.6V across it:

$$ R_2 = \frac{V_{R2}}{I_2} = \frac{3.6V}{0.36mA} = 10k\Omega $$

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Ohm's Law calculation.  You know that the desired Vout is 1.4V so we need to drop 5 - 1.4 volts across R2 when 0.36 mA is flowing.  So the answer would be:

R = V/I = (5 - 1.4)/0.00036 = 10K Ohms

What's happening with R1 is not related.